# Django, optimum wysiwyg editor + file browser combo for quick setup and easy maintenance

Tags: django, wysiwyg

I love Django but I've spent too long now (1 day) experimenting with different wysiwyg editor combinations when all I want to do is get something installed and get on with development.

Specifically, I'd like to know the following from experienced Django users: what is the optimum quick setup for a decent editor with a file browser?

I don't really want to have to install grappelli to have a file uploader - surely there is another option?  Also, I'm looking for the kind of file uploader which doesn't need 3 clicks to get to the point a user can upload an image.  Ideally, I'd like to use wymeditor but I see that the current package has a lot of dependencies which seem unnecessary (ie grappelli).

I've seen similar questions like this have been shutdown, note this isn't a subjective answer, I'm just looking for some advice on best practice when presented with a myriad of different options and methods of integration for something as basic as having an editor and file uploader ;)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have come to the conclusion that django-ckeditor is the best option, image browsing works fine once you have pillow.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem 1 day ago... Just go for the [django-pagedown](https://github.com/timmyomahony/django-pagedown). It is simple to install and easy to use. Remember that either you have to fork the project, or also download the [pagedown rep](https://github.com/timmyomahony/pagedown) (django-pagedown/static/pagedown)

It is very easy and fast to start working on.

Comment: I'm trying it right now, and I like the preview.  But what do use for image uploading for user's local system?